# Regular expressions Extraction Jmeter

Tags: asp.net, regex, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm trying to extract the following text in the header of a Response:

```
Location: example.aspx?X+Gy/a4DwC/og==
```

1. With the RegEx `Location: (.*)`, I can get this: `example.aspx?X+Gy/a4DwC/og==`
2. With the RegEx `Location: example.aspx?(.*)` I manage to get this: `?X+Gy/a4DwC/og==`

But just I need to extract `X+Gy/a4DwC/og==` without the question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a lookbehind to say that you need to match all starting after a `?`:

```
(?<=[?]).*
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZ9yA4/2). You may replace `*` with `+` to match at least 1 symbol. Use `$0$` template with this expression.

[Another alternative](https://regex101.com/r/pZ9yA4/2) is using a capturing regex `[?](.*)` with `$1$` template.

Comment: Shame on me, saw your answer too late (was typing one of my own).

Comment: It is not bad :) I did not use a named capture. Although I am not sure if using a named capture group with a lookbehind subpattern makes much sense. :)

Comment: You were not capturing at all :-) At least not in the code posted here.

Comment: Yes, it is what OP asked, perhaps. Let's hear from OP.

Comment: Why not (named capture)?

Comment: If OP uses `$0$` template then a whole match is passed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following pattern:

```
(?<=[?])(?<query>.*)
# Positive lookbehind looking for a question mark
# start a named capturing group called query, this will hold your output
```

See a demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lY7rO3/1).